# jQuery: get the element in position n of the result of the query

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the third span with value3 element. With the following query:

```
jQuery('span[class*="3"]:contains("value3")')
```

will return a list of span, and I need only the third. The question is how..

The site has the following structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><span class="1">value1</span></td>
            <td><span class="2">value2</span></td>
            <td><span class="3">value3</span></td>
            <td><span class="4">value4</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><span class="1">value1</span></td>
            <td><span class="2">value2</span></td>
            <td><span class="3">value3</span></td>
            <td><span class="4">value4</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><span class="1">value1</span></td>
            <td><span class="2">value2</span></td>
            <td><span class="3">value3</span></td>
            <td><span class="4">value4</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Edited some errors in my explanations..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery('span[class*="3"]:contains("value3")')[2]
```

should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
jQuery('span[class*="3"]:contains("value3")').eq(2);
```

From jQuery.com:

> .eq( index ) indexAn integer indicating the 0-based position of the
>   element.